# how to iterate each array element in response in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

First thing, the simple response which I get back from `$.ajax` is this:
 http://pastebin.com/eEE72ySk

I am using this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
    type: "Post",
    data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({
        'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()
    }, true),
    success: function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#responsestatus').text(result.Response.ResponseStatus);
    });
```

I was trying this code:

```
$.each(result.Response.Results[0][0].AirlineRemark, function (i, item) {
    $("#divResult1").append('<p>' + item.AirlineRemark + '</p>');
});
```

When I use the above code, then error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '5' in IndiGo

When I tried this code without the `forEach` loop :

```
 $("#divResult1").text(result.Response.Results[0][0].AirlineRemark);
```

I get no error but the output is only the first one. Indigo is showing however in response there are 20 arrays in Results. I have shown only two arrays in result in the link provided above.

Please someone tell me how to iterate each and every item in results array.

Comment: it will not work @PranavCBalan

Comment: jQuery is already deserialising the response for you, then you deserialise the resulting object again using `JSON.parse()`. Remove that and it should still work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6e5cueq0/

Comment: AirlineRemark is not an Array, so looping through that one is not possible. So loop through the array of arrays, and find the property within each loop

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually i am returning back back data in string form so i have to parse it. Just tell me how to show data from each array of results

Comment: `AirlineRemark` is a property of the first object in the nested array. Its not an array so you cannot use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

AirlineRemark is not an Array, so looping through that one is not possible. So loop through the array of arrays, and find the property within each loop

```
   $.each(result.Response.Results[0], function (i, item) {
      $("#divResult1").append('<p>' + item.AirlineRemark + '</p>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate a non-array there. If, `result` is based on your `JSON` that you provided. This is one way you can iterate it,

```
// Each items in result.Response.Results
$.each(result.Response.Results, function(i, items) {
  // Get the AirlineRemark at the item at 0 index.
  var airlineRemark = items[0].AirlineRemark;

  // Append it to #divResult1
  $("#divResult1").append('<p>' + airlineRemark + '</p>');
});
```

*Beware that on sample above, `items` is an array. And it will only get the first item.*

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
   $.each(result.Response.Results, function () {
      $("#divResult1").append('<p>'+this[0].AirlineRemark+'</p>');
    });
```